# Reliability of opensource ML packages

Tags: r, machine-learning, python, reliability, open-source

While working on a machine learning project, in addition to the widely known opensource ML packages like tidyverse (R), pandas/scikitlearn (python), we end up using lot of other little known packages, built for very specific purposes. As the open source packages are not regulated/moderated unlike SAS, how reliable will be the results from those packages. Quite often, those packages' github repos have existing unsolved issues and we may not go through them to identify any potential pitfalls.

Business will be making critical actions based on the predictions/insights we, as a data scientist provide, which in turn could be based on those packages. How can we minimize the risk in such scenarios ?

Comment: "existing unsolved issues" I'm sure these also exist in SAS libraries. Open source authors are just more transparent. You seem to have misconceptions what "regulated/moderated" by SAS actually means to you as a customer. In my opinion that's worth as much as your contract with them says they would pay you if a bug causes you damages.

Comment: Although not mathematical, the question is clearly relevant to applying computational statistics in the real world. One example I have seen is that people carefully maintain package versions and check the changes on a given data set to see if there are any big changes after any kind of re-training, update, or similar.